# Стоит ли делать динамическое добавление таблиц?

Tags: mysql

Вопрос в том, что система планируется с поддержкой многодоменности. Есть идея для каждого домена создавать свои таблицы. Ну естественно для того, чтобы снять поток запросов к одной таблице. Потому что если это будет несколько сайтов, то разные таблицы должны, по идее, помочь снять тормоза, связанные с выполнением UPDATE.

Но, с другой стороны, это дурной тон что ли. Собственно, что скажете?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте разные БД и mysqli...
ИМХО...

Comment: Ну в старой версии я таки использовал mysqli, сечас принял решение перейти на PDO. А вот про отедльные базы данных не совсем понял, вы предлагаете полностью дублировать настройки пользователей и все такое? Но это же создаст новые проблемы, например общая авторизация будет более кучерявой.

Comment: Я имел введу контент характерный для того или иного сайта разбивать на разные БД, для общего можно создать свою БД типа General там, я не знаю... Во всяком случае я бы однозначно делал бы именно так...